# Why cant I load an external resource from jQuery load method?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In the process of learning Ajax requests using jQuery, I tried to load google home page on the click of a link. So I wrote something like:

```
$("#ajax").click (function (event) {
    $("#g").html("Loading...");
    $("#g").load("http://www.google.com");
    event.preventDefault ();
});
```

And somewhere in body:

```
<a id="ajax" href="http://www.google.com">Load file ajax way</a>
<div id="g">Click the above link to load the page...</div>
```

Which didn't work and initially I thought there is some syntax error or something. But later when I replaced the google url with a static html file on server, it worked correctly.

```
$("#g").load("Temp.htm");
```

Is it designed to work like this (if yes, why?) or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Please can anyone explain (or refer) the security problem introduced by cross domain ajax calls? In other words, why it is safe to open another browser tab and open google but NOT from within the page? Is it to protect caller or callee?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Jquery uses an ajax (XMLHttpRequest) request to load the data, but the browser allows this for resources on the same domain. (The answers above mention the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). That's why it works with Temp.htm, but not www.google.com.

- One way to get around  this is to create a server script that will load the page for you - basically a proxy. Then you call

  ```
  $('#g').load("load.php?url=google.com")
  ```
- The other solution is to use iframes for communication - I found this library, that seems to be what you need: [jquery-crossframe](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-crossframe/)
- A third options is [JSONP](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29) but that would not work it your case.

My opinion - go for the first option with a server-side proxy.

---

Why is there a same origin policy?

Imagine that you are checking some stuff on your ebay account. Then in another tab you open my site, where I have a script that makes a series of requests to ebay (you are still logged in) and bids you for an Audi A8 without you even noticing. Annoying... If it was your bank it can directly steal money from you.

The irony is that despite the same origin policy, the above attack is still possible.

Comment: Very thorough and complete answer

Comment: so load.php just reads the queried domain and stores the contents?

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to make cross-domain AJAX calls for security reasons - see [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 1):

This is due to security. You can read all about it along with a solution over at [yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that you are not completely precluded from cross-domain requests in javascript.

As of jQuery 1.2, you can load JSON data located on another domain if you specify a JSON-P callback and the URL that you call supports JSON-P output.

The following example is straight from the jQuery docs. It grabs the last four flickr pics tagged with "cat".

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
      $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
        $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
      });
    });
```

You can read the docs here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON#urldatacallback

Personally I use it to pull in my latest tweets on my blog without having to build it into my server-side code. That also has the added benefit of not having to write error handling code for the often spotty API service from Twitter. Just view source on my blog if you wanna see it: http://joreteg.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to assume that you have a very good reason to do something that a link does by default with JavaScript...

The main reason is probably security: You can NOT access any data outside of the current domain from JavaScript.

Comment: I DON'T have any reason to do this. I was just doing this for learning jQuery and Ajax calls (and naively tried to use google). So probably I may never need to call other servers but it is still good to know the solutions if it is ever needed (suggested by Andy).

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://yoursite.com/"
```

in htaccess.send some parameters using

```
$("#g").load("http://www.google.com",{nomeaning:'nomeaning'});
```

this will send a post request.it worked for me