# Grabbing external URL's HTML via jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, same-origin-policy

I need to grab a specific DOM element (by ID) from an external URL via jQuery/AJAX. I know that this violates the same origin policy, but I can't find an acceptable workaround for when I'm specifically grabbing HTML (instead of JSON).

So say for example, I'm on website1.com, and I need to grab and output the contents of the #something element of website2.com. How can I do this using jQuery?

EDIT: Seems to be a duplicate of [Why cant I load an external resource from jQuery load method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292486/why-cant-i-load-an-external-resource-from-jquery-load-method) which has a good answer.

Comment: You can't. You will need a server side proxy script to fetch the HTML for you.

Comment: @Pekka, So, for example, if I'm working on a mobile device and as such am limited to HTML/CSS/JS, then it's just impossible?

Comment: yup. The Same Origin Policy is absolute - it must be in order to prevent security problems

Comment: Alright, thanks. Feel free to post as a real answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answering my own question):

Note that this is impossible in the browser because of the same origin policy. To get around it (like Pekka said in the comments above), you'd normally create a local proxy of the desired content. So like if you are working on website.com, and you need to grab a part of google.com, you could create website.com/google which would just be a clone of google.com via some server side code. Then you'd be free to do whatever you wanted to it, since it's on your domain.

The catch I was dealing with is that I was working on a BlackBerry WebWorks project, which means that I'm limited to HTML/CSS/JS, and I'm not actually *on* a website, so a proxy is impossible. Luckily, WebWorks lets you add trusted domains to each app you create, which means that the same origin policy doesn't apply to those domains.

Answer (score 0):

False.  The policy is not absolute as long as the server supports JSONP.  Google JSONP Jquery and you'll see tons of working examples doing what you want: returning webservice data from a domain other than your own via ajax.