# select xml child element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, xml-parsing

Is it possible to find an xml element by searching with the value of a child element?

So for  XML such as:

```
<route>
    <name>Lakeway</name>
    <abrv>LAKE</abrv>
    <eta>
        <time>00:30</time>
        <dest>MAIN</dest>
    </eta>
</route>
```

If I only have the value of the **abrv**, how would I parse the xml so as to get at the **eta** tags' child elements?

Is this doable with jQuery without looping through each element and comparing the values to the defined variable? Or is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I am trying to parse an XML feed from another domain. I'm not sure if I can do that with the xmlParse function, or if I'll need to use jQuery's Ajax functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var xmlString = "<route><name>Lakeway</name><abrv>LAKE</abrv><eta><time>00:30</time><dest>MAIN</dest></eta></route>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xmlString ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$abrv = $xml.find( "abrv" ).text() == "LAKE" ? $xml.find( "abrv" ) : false;

var time = $abrv.next().children("time").text();
var dest = $abrv.next().children("dest").text();

alert(time + " " + dest);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/UH2m5/

Hopefully, that could get you started.

Comment: How could I use this with an external XML file? That's what I was looking for actually.

Comment: You will need to bring the xml in using another method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292486/why-cant-i-load-an-external-resource-from-jquery-load-method

Comment: OK, so I used a simple proxy to get the XML, but I have another question. Is there a difference between using the parseXML function and using the $.get ajax function? So if instead of declaring an xml string, if I use $.get to get xml, should I be able to use the same selectors as you outline above?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to on the return xml.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `contains` filter to filter nodes based on this value.

Something like,

```
$(xml).find('abrv:contains(LAKE) + eta > *')
```

will return a jQuery object with two elements for the sample document.

```
<time>00:30</time>
<dest>MAIN</dest>
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/KVRXN/).