# Select text from a specific table cell on another page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a weird question. I want to create script in javascript (or PHP if I have to, I'm just more comfortable in javascript) that reads through a table until it finds specific text (know how to do that) and then returns the text three cells to the right.

To be specific, I want a script that finds a row for a specific printer on [this site](http://clusters.andrew.cmu.edu/printerstats/) and returns the printer's status. I know how to select unique text, but not so much about nonunique text.

Comment: Sure, you could do that with jQuery/Javascript.  I would start by looking at jQuery.get(), passing the URL of the link you provided.  You can wrap the response with a DIV tag and manipulate it as you would another jQuery object.

Comment: All of the functions here seem to return null after attempting to filter the element out.

Comment: (Oh, and I'm running them on the actual page, not trying to load them yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this is how you could do it using jQuery:

```
$("td").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === yourSeachText;
}).next().next().next().text();
```

Clarifying: the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function will select only the column whose text equals your search text, and each call to [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will return the column's next sibling - another `td`. Three calls later, you have the column you want, so you can get its text.

**Update**: you might also be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1292486/520779), if the site you're querying is not in the same domain as your script. If it **is**, you can simply load its contents to a div before querying it:

```
$("#placeholder").load("http://clusters.andrew.cmu.edu/printerstats/", function() {
    // The contents were loaded to #placeholder, do your query here
});
```

If it's **not**, then you'll have to load that html data somehow, and according to [an anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1292562/520779) to that question, your best route is really to do it in PHP (or at least use it to echo the other site's contents to your own).

Comment: @ShankarSangoli updated the answer with links to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
var printerName = 'yourname',
    status = $(':contains(' + printerName + ')').siblings().eq(2).text();
```

Comment: I think the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector will also match printers that have `printerName` as a **substring**, right? (which may or may not be a problem, and can even be desirable...)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.epi-dataTable tr:gt(0) td:first-child:contains("printerName")')
.closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').text();
```

Comment: I tried your script in Chrome's JS console, but the first line seems to return null (I'm substituting prn-hou-mudge-1 for printername, inside the quotes.)

Comment: That is because you don't have `jQuery` included in your site. Include the jQuery library and try it should work fine.

Comment: Ah, that would do it. Duh. Thanks!