# Why window.ready doesn't load external link Jquery

Tags: jquery, url, load

Hey guys I want to load a external link inside an element but nothing happens
here is the code I used...

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  $('#contador').load('http://counter2.freecounterstat.com/private/counter.js?c=36c0ded599f90fd9584581d3e2b02682'); 
});
```

and the html code ...

```
<div id='contador'></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `$(document).ready` your looking for, the is also `$(window).load`
Also the resource you want to load is a js file, which utilizes document.write so have to load it inline. Put it as a script tag at the bottom of you page

```
  <script src='http://counter2.freecounterstat.com/private/counter.js?c=36c0ded599f90fd9584581d3e2b02682'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I want load the url after window.load

Comment: but i want to charge the "hit visitors after all page loaded because the conection to hit visitor is too slow

Comment: @MarceloAlarcon That's why its at the bottom of the page, so it loads last

Answer (score 0):

[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) doesn't load external server but it loads the url from own server.

If you want to load external server [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292486/why-cant-i-load-an-external-resource-from-jquery-load-method)

Answer (score 0):

.load will open only the links within the site, for other links you have to use html Iframe.

Comment: I want load the url after window.load